# Tuning kafka streams for speed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two streams:

[topicA] -> processingA -> [topicB] -> processingB -> [topicC]

With logging in my application I have noticed that between sending output from processingA to topicB and picking message from topicB for processingB it takes more than 100ms (rather 150ms) each time. It might not be much, but it accumulates and finally rather simple cascade of processing takes almost second.

Can I tune kafka so that these delays are as close to zero as possible?
What config params have impact on these delays?

I have mostly default config. Is it commit.interval.ms that causes delay? I already changed it from much higher default value...

```
StreamsConfig values: 
    application.id = app
    application.server = 
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffered.records.per.partition = 1000
    cache.max.bytes.buffering = 10485760
    client.id = 
    commit.interval.ms = 100
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.deserialization.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler
    default.key.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    default.production.exception.handler = class org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.DefaultProductionExceptionHandler
    default.timestamp.extractor = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.FailOnInvalidTimestamp
    default.value.serde = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    num.standby.replicas = 0
    num.stream.threads = 1
    partition.grouper = class org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.DefaultPartitionGrouper
    poll.ms = 100
    processing.guarantee = exactly_once
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    replication.factor = 1
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    rocksdb.config.setter = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    state.cleanup.delay.ms = 600000
    state.dir = /tmp/kafka-streams
    topology.optimization = none
    upgrade.from = null
    windowstore.changelog.additional.retention.ms = 86400000
```

Comment: If I understood correct, you materialize your result stream after **processingA**. Can you avoid this materialization? You would just run your **processingB** right after the **processingA** (I suppose it returns a KStream insatnce)

Comment: @dmkvl sorry, but it must go through topic. there are other processes that also produce topicB messages...

Answer (score 0):

The 100 to 150ms seems normal in your situation as you have set commit.interval.ms = 100 (which is also the default for processing.guarantee = exactly_once).
With exactly once processingB will only read messages that have been commited in [topicB], and processingA will only commit after (at least) 100ms.

Without re-architecting your system, you could tune commit.interval.ms for a better latency, but if you lower that value, the throughput will also be lower.

See  [this post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/enabling-exactly-once-kafka-streams/) (Streams Performance Implications) which describes this trade-of.

Comment: can I set commit.interval.ms to sth much smaller, like 10ms?
re-architecting is still an option, but what exactly you mean by that? I cannot avoid posting to topic "topicB", I need persistency here and also it is joint point with other processes

Comment: I can also see that these delays can be much higher than just commit interval - i.e. for commit.interval=50ms I observe 250ms delays...

Comment: I looks like you cannot simply re-architect as you need to go through topicB... And I cannot give more advice if 250ms is normal or not, it really depends on your kafka cluster. You could measure latency and throughput on your cluster to have a baseline to be able to measure the overhead added by using kafka streams with exactly once.

Comment: Setting commit interval too low is not recommended as it implies quite some overhead for Kafka Streams and on the broker and may impact your throughput significantly. -- The question is, where the latency comes from (read or write?). Maybe you can reduce `linger.ms` config for the producer? Or reduce producer batch size? For consumer size, maybe `max.poll.records` config may reduce latency. Note, that reducing all those setting, will take a hit on throughput (it's the classic throughput vs latency tradeoff).

Comment: linger.ms is set to 0, network latency does not matter, as I am running kafka and zookeeper in docker images on single machine. Will try to experiment with other mentioned configs

Answer (score 0):

what is your consumer/processingA polling frequency ?

try to reduce that so that your processor will consume the data quickly

and also your `poll.ms` is set to 100ms reduce that as well and see if that helps.

Comment: Seems this gives best effect. Reducing poll.ms and commit.interval.ms to 50ms I was able to reduce delays to below 100ms

Comment: @redguy Glad to know that